# File with irregular spaces and tabs split/explode columnwise

Tags: php, string, split

So I have a very old file with thousands of lines (I guess generated by hand) and I'm trying to move them into a rdb, but the lines don't have a format/pattern to convert into columns. Say for example the lines in the file looks like:

```
blah   blahsdfas    laslkdlasdj      aksdjla
sldks  slslsl      lsdlksldj           lsdjlfslk
```

I could say it has four fields when I look at it, primarily tried using awk but it wasn't printing the column as expected because the space between a column is not tab or with an equal space count.

You guys think its possible to extract? If yes can someone help with a php snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split), you can break the line up using one or more whitespace characters as the delimiters:

```
$lines = file('filename', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $pieces = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
    // do something with pieces
}
```

Comment: this is what I was about to write, I would just suggest using `\s\s+` as the pattern to split on more than one space in case a string actually has a space that is needed.

Comment: @Tim: Cool will try this too, kudos, you guys are blazing fast!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $line)` would split this apart. That'd split on two or more whitespace characters.

If this has been maintained by hand, you may have to do manual cleanup (e.g., maybe someone typed two spaces but didn't intend to start the next column). At only thousands of lines, manual cleanup is thankfully on tedious, not impossible.

Comment: thanks @derobert for the quick reply, will check it out..
yeah, the file is a big mess.. just hate to even think of manually cleaning up thousands and thousands of lines.

Comment: thanks a bunch @derobert, just applied to the chunk of file I had and almost 80% is cleaned up :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. If you can classify the failed 20%, you may be able to write more rules to catch those cases, then repeat. Eventually you get few enough failures that you just clean those up by hand.